# Estimate machine processing power

Tags: php

I got this brilliant idea of a simple way to estimate processing power.

```
$now = microtime(true);
$ops = 0;

while (microtime(true) - $now < 0.100) {
    $ops++;
}

echo $ops;
```

Is it fair to use this code to grade processing power of multiple machines? Obviously the measuring unit will be imaginary, but could the results of this be considered valid?

*Assuming all tested machines run the same version of PHP*.

Comment: basically, you're implementing something similar to a PHP-version of **[BogoMips](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BogoMips)** - it is *kind of* useful for crudely evaluating the raw processing power of a single thread - but you're forgetting that RAM, storage, network, the amount of CPU-cores and many more factors are just as important - if not even more so.

Comment: I just tested this on a couple machines, something very interesting I found out - on the *same* machine using php5.6 the result was **52K**, running php7.1 result was **1.25M**. I was pretty surprised.

Comment: Unless you can control for all the other threads running on the machine at the same time which may skew your results, or you're taking *a lot* of samples, just this in itself is hardly guaranteed to be accurate.